# How to perform regression on dataset with varying number of observations for each athlete?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures

I am trying to figure out the finishing times of different marathon runners in a race by using their past racing times and personal data to predict their finishing times in an upcoming race that they will all take part in. The actual variables to be considered are the same across different athletes and include things such as weather, distance run, personal best time, split times etc.

My issue is that some athletes have run 5 past marathons and hence have 5 sets of past data (e.g 5 sets of weather data), while others have run say 20 and have 4 times as much (20 sets of weather data). How do I create a model so that I can equally compare the past data to predict future performance when they all have varying amounts of past data?

P.s apologies for any ambiguity, I am quite new to stats and model creation.

Comment: This is repeated measurements data. I added that tag, look through post with it!

Comment: Thank @kjetilbhalvorsen for pointing me in the direction of repeated measures and editing the question. Much obliged!